# Google Tag Manager - Primary Expression Expected

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Following is my code:

```
<script>
    <button type = "button"
    onclick="sce.event('mw_button_click', {
    ...});>
    </button>
</script>
```

And when i try to enter the debug mode in **Google Tag Manager** I have an error:

> Error in line 2 character 4: Pare error. Primary expression expected.

Does anyone know how to fix it and can help me?

Comment: I think you are missing a " for enclosing sce.event

Answer (score 1):

If you use the button tag inside the script tag it doesn't work in GTM .Instead you should use Javascript or Jquery like I mentioned below

The below is an example from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp . Hope this helps

// Get the button, and when the user clicks on it, execute myFunction
    `document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction()};`

/* myFunction toggles between adding and removing the show class, which is used to hide and show the dropdown content */

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your onclick event into a function of its own.

Like this:

```
<script>
  function myEvent() {
    ...do code
  }

  <button 
    type = "button"
    onclick="myEvent('mw_button_click')">
  </button>
</script>
```